# Can I change the Y-Axis label display as I zoom in/out of a dygraphs chart?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I've created a dygraphs chart that displays the movement of tagged fish, with time plotted on the x-axis and distance moved displayed on the y-axis.  There are a dozen or more detection sites in the river, each site approx. 30-100 km from its neighbor.  Each detection site has four or more detectors, labeled 'D1', 'D2', ... 'Dx'.  The initial chart contains labels on the y-axis spanning almost 600km.  At that resolution, I'd like to see only the major labels for the detection sites, e.g., 'Lock 1', Lock 2', 'Lock 6', etc.  As I drill down to a given site, then and only then would I like to see the minor labels for the individual detectors at that site ('D1', 'D2', etc.)

I'm using a ticker function in dygraphs to map my y-axis labels to the corresponding river location. I would like the minor labels to appear on the axis only when I zoom into a site, such that only that site's own **major** label appears, along with the minor labels for that site.

[image: Portion of an JS associative array used to map labels to the y-axis.]

Can I use a callback function to return the current y-resolution?  Do I need, and can I switch between, two source lists, dependent on the y-resolution?

[image: Initial view of the chart, with a y-axis range of ~600 km.]

[image: Intermediate zoom, displaying three four on the y-axis.]

[image: Zoomed in on Lock 9. Here, and only at this scale, I want to display the indivdual detectors ('D1', 'D2', etc.]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to incorporate a ticker generator/modifier function within the Dygraphs ticker option, and passing that function the parameter I wanted to test for each time the graph was being redrawn.  In my application, I pass and test for a suitably small interval in the **yAxisRange()**, but in the simple example below I test only for the **isZoomed** status of the y-axis.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="dgraphChartContainer" style="width:800px; height:600px;border:2px solid;border-radius:5px;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      //Define global variables
      var myLocationTable =
         [
                ["            D1",1001],
                ["            D2",1002],
                ["Station #1 ---",1002.5],
                ["            D3",1003],
                ["            D4",1004],

                ["            D1",2001],
                ["            D2",2002],
                ["Station #2 ---",2002.5],
                ["            D3",2003],
                ["            D4",2004],

                ["            D1",3001],
                ["            D2",3002],
                ["Station #3 ---",3002.5],
                ["            D3",3003],
                ["            D4",3004]
         ];

        function makeTickerList(isZoomed) {
         var myTempArray = [];
         var myTempObject = {};
         for (var i=0; i < myLocationTable.length; i++) {
                if (isZoomed) {
                    myTempObject = {
                        v: myLocationTable[i][1],
                        label: myLocationTable[i][0]
                    }
                } else {
                    myTempObject = {
                        v: myLocationTable[i][1],
                        label: (myLocationTable[i][0]).slice(0,-2)
                    }
                }
            myTempArray.push(myTempObject);
         }
         return myTempArray;
      }

        var vGraph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dgraphChartContainer"),
        [
            [ new Date("2010/09/30 21:00:00"),null,null,null ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/01 03:00:00"),1001,2003,3004 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/01 09:00:00"),1002,2001,3003 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/01 15:00:00"),1003,2002,3002 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/01 21:00:00"),1004,2004,3001 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/02 03:00:00"),2001,3001,2004 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/02 09:00:00"),2002,3002,2003 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/02 15:00:00"),2003,3003,2002 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/02 21:00:00"),2004,3004,2001 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/03 03:00:00"),3001,1004,1004 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/03 09:00:00"),3002,1002,1003 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/03 15:00:00"),3003,1003,1002 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/03 21:00:00"),3004,1004,1001 ],
            [ new Date("2010/10/04 03:00:00"),null,null,null ]
        ],
            { //options
                labels: ["Event Date","Me","Myself","Irene"],
                axes: {
                         y: {
                         ticker: function(min, max, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
                             return makeTickerList(dygraph.isZoomed("y"));
                         } //ticker closure
                        } //y-axis closure
                },  //end of axes declarations
                title: "Dynamic Y-Axis Ticker Test",
            strokeWidth: 2,
                yAxisLabelWidth: 110
            }  //options closure
        );  // end of dygraph declaration
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This displays only the "Station#x -" tick labels when the graph is drawn in full, but reveals the full labels for all five ticks per station when the user zooms in on the y-axis.  Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davem/w72FQ/2/).

In this example I use or modify a single set of mapped tick marks, but this dynamic approach could be used to generate a new set of ticks, based on content, each time the graph is drawn.